# Command Prompt closes on Windows, using Wamp Server commands

Tags: php, mysql, wamp

I am following the tutorial on PHP with MySQL. In that tutorial ebook, they recommend us to use commands to set password for the MySQL. The command goes something like this, "mysqladmin -u root -p status"

Now, I am using Windows XP and whenever I enter the command, the dos screen flashes and terminates. I am unable to note down the results, so the question: is there any way to stop command prompt from terminating on Windows machine?

Looking forward to hear from you guys, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are running the command from the Run menu in windows.

Open a command window by typing 'cmd' in the run window and type in your command on that console.

Answer (score 1):

Open up a command prompt so that you have a persistent environment. Do it by running `cmd.exe` from the Start->Run (or WinKey+R) dialog.